# How to replace left recursion in boost spirit x3?

Tags: c++, boost, abstract-syntax-tree, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I’m currently trying to parse recursive expressions like `***a` and `a***` with boost spirit x3.

So I defined my abstract syntax tree as follows:

```
namespace client {
    namespace ast {

        struct pointer;

        struct type : x3::variant<
                char, x3::forward_ast<pointer>
        > {
            using base_type::base_type;
            using base_type::operator=;
        };

        struct pointer{
            type t;
        };
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(client::ast::pointer,
                          t
)
```

It will result in nested pointers with a character for the last type.

If I'm trying to parse `***a`, I can simply define the following rules:

```
x3::rule<class t1, ast::type> type_rule = "type_rule";
auto simple_type_rule = x3::rule<class t1, char> {} = x3::lower;
auto pointer_type_rule = x3::rule<class t1, ast::pointer> {} = x3::lit('*') > type_rule;
auto type_rule_def = x3::rule<class t1, ast::type> {} = pointer_type_rule | simple_type_rule;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(type_rule);
```

It parses successfully :)

Now I'd like to parse an expression like `a***`.

The problem - I think - is, that the relating rules are left recursive,
ending with a segmentation fault, because of a stackoverflow.

So for eliminating the left recursion, I thought of using a grammar
like this:

```
auto simple_type_rule = x3::rule<class t1, char> {} = x3::lower;
x3::rule<class t1, x3::unused_type> pointer_suffix = "pointer_suffix";
auto pointer_suffix_def = (x3::lit('*') > pointer_suffix) | x3::eps;
auto type_rule = x3::rule<class t1, ast::type> {} =  simple_type_rule > pointer_suffix;

BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(pointer_suffix);
```

This parses succesfully, but as you might have noticed, I used unused_type,
as I didn't know, what I might return.
Generally I'd like to have it nested like in the example before.
Do I have to return a std::vector of a dummy struct, which I have to convert
to my desired struct by a semantic action?
Or should I try to solve it by the usage of x3::with?
It seems to me a bit odd.

What is the recommended approach?

Thx

CSpille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PEG aren't well suited here. You basically can make it but only very inefficiently. I would not hesitate to change my AST to simply represent the level of indirection with an integral number instead.

### If you really want, read on

Instead, here you can very easily use a semantic action that wraps the *already-parsed type* with a pointer each time we encounter a trailing '*'.

The semantic action to do it would simply assign the pointer-wrapped version of the rule attribute back to itself:

```
auto wrap_pointer = [](auto& ctx) {
    _val(ctx) = ast::pointer { _val(ctx) };
};
```

Which you could use:

```
auto type_rule = identifier >> *(x3::lit('*') [ wrap_pointer ]);
```

### Full Demo

I changed around some names and I /think/ I might swapped around the terms for pointer-rule vs. type rule (`*a` is an expression, `a*` is a type).

However, the code works and should be self-explanatory. I even threw in a debug visualizer:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, type const& t) {
    struct {
        std::ostream& _os;
        void operator()(ast::type const& t) const { boost::apply_visitor(*this, t); }
        void operator()(ast::identifer identifier) const { _os << identifier; }
        void operator()(ast::pointer const& p) const { _os << "pointer("; operator()(p.t); _os << ')'; }
    } vis{os};
    return vis(t), os;
}
```

So you can see the parsed results.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60d7bb55e4fd12ec)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace ast {
    using identifer = char;

    struct pointer;

    struct type : x3::variant<identifer, x3::forward_ast<pointer>> {
        using base_type::base_type;
        using base_type::operator=;
    };

    struct pointer {
        type t;
    };

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, type const& t) {
        struct {
            std::ostream& _os;
            void operator()(ast::type const& t) const { boost::apply_visitor(*this, t); }
            void operator()(ast::identifer identifier) const { _os << identifier; }
            void operator()(ast::pointer const& p) const { _os << "pointer("; operator()(p.t); _os << ')'; }
        } vis{os};
        return vis(t), os;
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::pointer, t)

namespace parser {
    auto const identifier = x3::rule<class t1, ast::identifer> {"identifier"} = x3::lower;

    x3::rule<class t2, ast::type> pointer_expression = "pointer_expression";
    auto pointer_expression_def 
        = (x3::rule<class t1, ast::pointer> {"indirection"} = '*' > pointer_expression) | identifier;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(pointer_expression)

    x3::rule<class t3, ast::type, true> type_rule = "type_rule";
    auto wrap_pointer = [](auto& ctx) {
        _val(ctx) = ast::pointer { _val(ctx) };
    };
    auto type_rule_def = identifier >> *(x3::lit('*') [ wrap_pointer ]);

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(type_rule)
}

int main() {
    auto run = [](std::initializer_list<char const*> inputs, auto rule, auto title) {
        for (std::string const input : inputs) {
            std::cout << "====== " << title << ": " << std::quoted(input) << " ======\n";
            auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
            ast::type t;
            if (parse(f, l, rule, t)) {
                std::cout << "Parsed: " << t << "\n";
            } else {
                std::cout << "Failed\n";
            }

            if (f!=l) {
                std::cout << "Remaining input: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
            }
        }
    };

    run({"", "a", "*a", "**a"}, parser::pointer_expression, "expression");
    run({"", "b", "b*", "b**"}, parser::type_rule, "type");
}
```

Prints

```
====== expression: "" ======
Failed
====== expression: "a" ======
Parsed: a
====== expression: "*a" ======
Parsed: pointer(a)
====== expression: "**a" ======
Parsed: pointer(pointer(a))
====== type: "" ======
Failed
====== type: "b" ======
Parsed: b
====== type: "b*" ======
Parsed: pointer(b)
====== type: "b**" ======
Parsed: pointer(pointer(b))
```

Comment: Thx, it lookes exactly like, what I wanted to have :) What is the purpose of the last template parameter for type_rule (force_attribute = true)? It also seems to work without it...

Comment: @Spille it's to make explicit that even though we have semantic actions, we still want automatic attribute propagation. TBH I think it only "seems" to work otherwise, because in theory you'd have to have another semantic action on the identifier to assign the "primary" attribute: `identifier [ ([](auto& ctx) { x3::_val(ctx) = x3::_attr(ctx); }) ]`